# regex capture info in text file after multiple blank lines

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I open a complex text file in python, match everything else I need with regex but am stuck with one search.

I want to capture the numbers after the 'start after here' line. The space between the two rows is important and plan to split later.

```
start after here: test


5.7,-9.0,6.2

1.6,3.79,3.3
```

Code:

```
text = open(r"file.txt","r") 
for line in text:
    find = re.findall(r"start after here:[\s]\D+.+", line)
```

I tried this here https://regexr.com/ and it seems to work but it is for Java.

It doesn't find anything. I assume this is because I need to incorporate multiline but unsure how to read file in differently or incorporate. Have been trying many adjustments to regex but have not been successful.

Comment: All the lines after have to start with a digit and decimal?

Comment: Yes, there is additional text after, but only want to capture the numbers; they all share the same format.

Comment: Tip: Use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to test your regex, you can even set the language to python.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `start after here:[\s]\D+.+` matches the literal words and then a whitespace char using `[\s]` (you can omit the brackets).

Then 1+ times not a digit is matched, which will match until before `5.7`. Then 1+ times any character except a newline will be matched which will match `5.7,-9.0,6.2` It will not match the following empty line and the next line.

One option could be to match your string and match all the lines after that do not start with a decimal in a capturing group.

```
\bstart after here:.*[\r\n]+(\d+\.\d+.*(?:[\r\n]+[ \t]*\d+\.\d+.*)*).*
```

The values including the empty line are in the first capturing group.

For example

```
import re

regex = r"\bstart after here:.*[\r\n]+(\d+\.\d+.*(?:[\r\n]+[ \t]*\d+\.\d+.*)*).*"

test_str = ("start after here: test\n\n\n"
    "5.7,-9.0,6.2\n\n"
    "1.6,3.79,3.3\n")

matches = re.findall(regex, test_str)

print(matches)
```

Result

```
['5.7,-9.0,6.2\n\n1.6,3.79,3.3']
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w0aVqg/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/JFwwib)

If you want to match the decimals (or just one or more digits) before the comma you might split on 1 or more newlines and use:

```
[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)(?=,|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1ZPNrn/3)

Comment: Thanks; trying to incorporate your code in Python now

Comment: Ah, you mean it is for Python?  I thought for Java. Then I have to update the current pattern, 1 mom.

Comment: @Ethe99 I have update the answer for Python. In Python it will work like this https://ideone.com/JFwwib

Comment: This makes sense. But can't seem to match with the breaks. It works on your example, even when I change the text string. Have been experimenting with replacing line breaks to see what could be missing.

Comment: If you want the individual decimal numbers you could split on one or more linebreaks `\n+`. That will give you the individual line. Then split on a comma to get the decimals.

Comment: The sequence of numbers (they are much longer than example) is important, so want to keep like that, just can't capture the numbers after the text start. I want to keep sequences together but maintain that space in any way possible. If I can just get it to capture the numbers I can split on the space as you suggest!

Comment: You could use split and then use `[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?` to get all the individual numbers using for example `re.findall` See the regex demo https://regex101.com/r/1ZPNrn/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

test_str = ("start after here: test\n\n\n"
    "5.7,-9.0,6.2\n\n"
    "1.6,3.79,3.3\n")


m = re.search(r'start after here:([^\n])+\n+(.*)', test_str)
new_str = m[2]
m = re.search(r'(-?\d*\.\d*,?\s*)+', new_str)
print(m[0])
```

Comment: This works well to capture the numbers, but need to keep the breaks (there are additional rows and some unrelated numbers and text after).

Comment: Thank you -  So this works perfectly but am gonna do this on a bunch of files - the text after the colon in string "s" will change slightly each time. I tried this up through colon but capture only produces a '.' - there are . in string after colon if that matters.

Comment: Altered file and see it is because there are periods after the colon - like test . next. next -

Comment: Sorry about that, again (having a bad day). I think it's finally right. I am looking for 'start after here:' followed by anything on the same line followed by one or more new lines.

Comment: Your current pattern will also match a dot or a dot and comma because the digits match 0+ times. See https://regex101.com/r/1ZPNrn/2

Comment: @regex101.com/r/1ZPNrn/2: You are absolutely correct and I was well aware of that. My assumption was that it wasn't going to be a problem not knowing what else was going to possibly follow. The correct regex for decimal numbers is more complicated than the upvoted one. For example, it will not recognize `.32`.